# A more accurate way of inferring quantiles

Tags: r, quantiles

So … I'd like to know which IQ score (sd=15) corresponds to a given percentile.

The straigtforward way in R is to ask

`quantile(rnorm(sample,100,15),percentile,0)`

Where `percentile` is between 0 and 100 and `sample` is a very large number. Occasionally, not large enough for sufficient accuracy.

Does R have a more accurate algorithm? I've googled, and found math that's over my head to the extent that I can't turn it into R code.

Any and all hints and suggestions appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`qnorm` is your friend.

For example 50th and 90th percentiles:

```
qnorm(.5,100,15)
[1] 100

qnorm(.9,100,15)
[1] 119,2233
```